JMeter | JSON Path Extractor Query | Unable to obtain id from JSON on the basis of two filters
I have been trying to generate a JSON query for JSON Path Extractor of JMeter to obtain all task ids where 'category' does 'not contain Docebo' and where 'userTasks' have 'completed' status marked as 'false' for the following JSON response (sub response shared here):
     {
       "user": [
         {
           "id": 3633,
           "guid": "j25c9340-dert0-1113f-wkk2-000008fdb94",
           "firstname": "abc",
           "lastname": "xyz",
           "preferredname": null,
           "active": true,
           "roleKey": 1,
           "userTags": [
             {
               "id": 12345,
               "userKey": 2323,
               "tagKey": 79
             },
             {
               "id": 12332,
               "userKey": 1233,
               "tagKey": 897
             },
            {
               "id": 12313,
               "userKey": 1233,
               "tagKey": 234
             },
             {
               "id": 12345,
               "userKey": 4321,
               "tagKey": 23
             },
             {
               "id": 139334,
               "userKey": 3633,
               "tagKey": 53
             }
           ]
         }
       ],
       "tasks": [
         {
           "id": 09876,
           "title": "Submit Performance Report",
           "description": "Test data",
           "creatorKey": 0909,
           "referenceNum": null,
           "referenceVal": null,
           "dueDate": "2023-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
           "goLiveDate": "2023-06-18T00:00:05.147Z",
           "closeDate": "2023-09-10T00:00:00.000Z",
           "archiveDate": null,
           "highPriority": false,
           "draft": false,
           "mandatory": true,
           "additionalDetails": "",
           "verificationDetails": "",
           "estimatedDuration": null,
           "estimatedDurationLabel": "30TO60MINUTES",
           "category": "Docebo",
           "level": "Individual",
           "journeyRole": null,
           "actionType": null,
           "verificationType": null,
           "externalLink": "https://testdata.b23sosaas.com/learn/course/9018/A-000M1",
           "isExternallyManaged": true,
           "sourceSystemId": 1,
           "externalId": "5678",
           "requiresProof": false,
           "archived": false,
           "lastUpdatedByStaffAt": "2023-06-17T11:47:37.062Z",
           "lastUpdatedByStaffKey": null,
           "taskOwners": [],
           "creator": {
             "id": 12312,
             "guid": "efrerertret-fgfg-2323-dgf33-rerer343231",
             "firstname": "FIRSTNAME",
             "lastname": "LASTNAME",
             "preferredname": null,
             "active": true,
             "roleKey": 6
           },
           "taskTags": [],
           "userTasks": [
             {
               "id": UTID123456,
               "dueDate": null,
               "lastUpdatedDate": null,
               "lastUpdatedAction": null,
               "completed": false,
               "requiresProof": false,
               "additionalDetails": null,
               "approverComments": null,
               "proofOfCompletionKey": null,
               "userKey": 3003,
               "approverKey": null,
               "lastUpdatedByKey": null,
               "taskKey": 15223,
               "sourceSystemId": null,
               "externalId": "9001",
               "externalUrl": null
             }
                ]
         },
         {
           "id": 009911,
           "title": "Seminar & Seminar at Socialization Event",
           "description": "Learning Environment",
           "creatorKey": 3421,
           "referenceNum": null,
           "referenceVal": null,
           "dueDate": "2023-07-02T16:30:00.000Z",
           "goLiveDate": "2023-06-30T16:30:00.000Z",
           "closeDate": "2023-07-03T18:30:00.000Z",
           "archiveDate": null,
           "highPriority": false,
           "draft": false,
           "mandatory": true,
           "additionalDetails": "",
           "verificationDetails": "",
           "estimatedDuration": null,
           "estimatedDurationLabel": "90MINUTESORMORE",
           "category": "SEMINAR",
           "level": "Individual",
           "journeyRole": null,
           "actionType": null,
           "verificationType": null,
           "externalLink": "https://abc.seminar.com/learn/course/6262/I-007",
           "isExternallyManaged": true,
           "sourceSystemId": 1,
           "externalId": "6222 / B897JJ",
           "requiresProof": false,
           "archived": false,
           "lastUpdatedByStaffAt": "2023-06-17T11:47:40.466Z",
           "lastUpdatedByStaffKey": null,
           "taskOwners": [],
           "creator": {
             "id": 9800,
             "guid": "wew23sd2f-wejyj-2357-fg24-er3g4523fa66f",
             "firstname": "FIRSTSEMINAR",
             "lastname": "LASTSEMINAR",
             "preferredname": null,
             "active": true,
             "roleKey": 9
           },
           "taskTags": [],
           "userTasks": [
             {
               "id": 4556688,
               "dueDate": null,
               "lastUpdatedDate": null,
               "lastUpdatedAction": null,
               "completed": false,
               "requiresProof": false,
               "additionalDetails": null,
               "approverComments": null,
              "proofOfCompletionKey": null,
              "userKey": 4546,
              "approverKey": null,
              "lastUpdatedByKey": null,
              "taskKey": 122445,
              "sourceSystemId": null,
              "externalId": "4566 / B7no4J",
              "externalUrl": null
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }

Query which was attempted:
      $.tasks.[?(@.category =~ /(?!Docebo)(.*?)/i  && @.userTasks.[?(@.completed == 'false')])].id

I am not well versed with the JSON queries and looking for inputs to get going to have all task id which have category not containing Docebo and where userTasks are marked as false for completed.

Requesting support here please...am badly stuck with a deliverable!

I think you need to amend your JSONPath Expression to look like:
$..tasks.*[?(!(@.category != 'Docebo') && @.userTasks.[?(@.completed == 'false')])].id

More information:

JSONPath: Filter Operators
JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios


Thanks Ivan for sharing your inputs. However, as per the query shared by you, I wont be able to filter category wherein Docebo-XYZ is mentioned. Also, first part of my query works fine. Its after concatenation that query doesn't work in JMeter. Unable to figure out why so.

Sharing execution outcome - Query could not filter Docebo out. As far as my attempts goes, != 'Docebo' always failed as well.
